# De-normalizing capacitor and inductor values when resistances are different

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, circuit-design, inductor

I need to know when we de-normalize capacitor and inductor values when the source resistance and load resistance are not equal to each other. How to de-normalize the inductor or capacitor?

The equation is like this:

[image]

So the problem is: what is this *R*<sub>0</sub> in this equation if we got a different source resistor and load resistor which are different from each other?

So how to de-normalize capacitance/inductance if I have a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

Denormalisation is required in the context of a filter design from tables, (for instance Zverev or A.B.Williams) where the tabulated values are given in terms of a filter that has a 1 Ω impedance and a 1 rad/s corner frequency.

If source and load resistances are not equal, the default one will be 1 Ω, the other will be given as a different value, or 0, or infinity. Denormalise with respect to the resistor in the 1 Ω position.